# Populate textarea field with prototype

Tags: ajax, magento, input, request, prototype

Im struglling to autopopulating with prototype an textarea field. When costumer click `<a href="#" onclick="SubmitPayshop();"/>GERAR</a>`, they get response from a php file and should populate the textarea field.

The code above sucessfuly populate a specific DIV (commented in code), but i need to populate textarea `<textarea style="width: 100%;height: 45px;" type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Payshop') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="pay_check_no" name="payment[check_no]" /></textarea>`

Was triyng .update `$('pay_check_no').value='***response from php***'`. But no luck.

Could someone help me please?

Regards and thx

```
<script>

function SubmitPayshop()
{

  new Ajax.Request('/payshop.php', {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: successFunc,
  onFailure:  failureFunc
  });

}

function successFunc(response){

     if (200 == response.status){
        alert("A sua referência foi criada com sucesso!");
    }
    var container = $('pay_check_no');
    var content = response.responseText;
    container.update(content);
}

function failureFunc(response){

     alert("Ocorreu um erro. Se deseja este método contate a loja diretamente." );

}
</script>

<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>" >
    <div id="pay_check_no" name="payment[check_no]"></div>
    <li>
        <span class="input-box">
            <textarea style="width: 100%;height: 45px;" type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Payshop') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="pay_check_no" name="payment[check_no]" /></textarea>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you insert your actual code, because I see commented `a`, `div` and `textarea` with same `id`s and textarea closed two times `/></textarea>`.

Comment: Also the textarea see to be hidden because of `style="display:none;"` of UL

Comment: Let me explain. This is a payment gateway. When customer select PAYSHOT as payment, <ul> display atributte change to block. And then customer must call WEBSERVICE and php should populate the right order.save field

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with same `id="pay_check_no"`, and when you trying to change `$('pay_check_no').value` looks like `$('pay_check_no')` refers to 'div' element not to `input`, just try to use different `id`s

Comment: the div id is just for your reference. I know that must be unique. ignore div because there isnt in original code. thx

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$('pay_check_no').value`

Also ID should be unique

```
<div **id="pay_check_no"** name="payment[check_no]"></div>
<li>
    <span class="input-box">
        <textarea ...**id="pay_check_no"** name="payment[check_no]" /></textarea>
    </span>
</li>
```